# Getting unknown host exception for mysql in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am getting exception in .gitlab-ci.yml file when trying to commit in gitlab.

```
.gitlab-ci.yml:
    image: 'maven:3-jdk-8'
    stages:
      - test
      - build
    services:
      - 'mysql:5.5'
      - 'mongo:3.6'
    variables:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'test'
      MYSQL_USER: 'root'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_HOST: 'mysql'
      MYSQL_PORT: '3306'
    cache:
      paths:
        - .m2/repository
        -  target
    maven-test:
      stage: test
      script: "mvn test"
    maven-build:
      stage: build
      script: "mvn package"
      artifacts:
        paths:
          - target/*.jar
```

Application.yml file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST}:3306/${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    username: ${MYSQL_USER}
    password: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
```

Exception:

[image]

Unable to find out where I am doing mistake.

Comment: Does it help if you define MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/mysql.html

Comment: I have added MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD in the environment variables but still it was getting the exception.

Comment: I can't see the exception that you have posted, some problem with imgur probably. Can you type it in directly in your question instead?

Answer (score 1):

After updating the .gitlab-ci.yml file it was resolved.
Previously I am given my local mysql password but it was not working. Then changing in .yml file the mysql password as 'root' works. 
It was not clear to me why mysql password 'root' only be accepted.If anybody has idea please clarify.

```
image: 'maven:3-jdk-8'
stages:
  - test
  - build
services:
  - 'mysql:5.5'
  - 'mongo:3.6'
variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASENAME: 'TEST'
  MYSQL_HOST: 'mysql'
  MYSQL_URL: 'jdbc:mysql://mysql/SBA?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true'
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
  MYSQL_USERNAME: 'root'
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'root'
  MONGO_DATABASE: 'TEST'
  MONGO_HOST: 'mongo'
  MONGO_PORT: '27017'
cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository
    -  target
maven-test:
  stage: test
  script: "mvn test"
maven-build:
  stage: build
  script: "mvn package"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
```